# Copies of a pointer into a pointer doesn't work in C

Tags: c

I have a function with two pointers in parameters. The first pointers(Position *x) points on a struct which have values, the second on nothing(Position *y) (it has not been initialized yet). I try to copy my first pointer into the second and then to printf the values from the second pointer but it doesn't work. I don't understand. Does it mean that you can change the value of a pointer but not his adress since in reality C language always works by value(i mean in parameter transfer) ?

```
void waitDeplacement(Position *oldPosition, Position *newPosition, Sens *sens, Niveau *niveau)
{   ...
    newPosition = oldPosition;
    printf("NEW POSITION x:%d / y:%d\n", newPosition->x, newPosition->y);
    ...
}
```

Beside, When I use a deep copy:

```
*newPosition = *oldPosition;
```

it work. So why please ?

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow ! *"I try to copy my first pointer into the second and then to printf the values from the second pointer but it doesn't work"* . Please show your code attempt in your question this will help a lot your question to be well received. Also, define "doesn't work" -> do you have wrong output ? An exception ? In any case, please describe precisely what happens. And have a look at this help topic : [mcve]

Comment: You can change the pointer locally in the function, but it won't find its way back to the caller just by doing that.

Comment: No I don't have any exception. Just values to 0. I have try to make the printf into the function so I work locally and it doesn't work.

Comment: I would say that, given this small example, `printf("NEW POSITION x:%d / y:%d\n", oldPosition->x, oldPosition->y);` would give the same output, meaning what you expect those values to be is incorrect.

Comment: Hint:  print out the values of the ***pointers***  in the code that calls `waitDeplacement()`, both before and *after* the call.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Be sure that everything work in the C language if you know this language. Pointers too but it is quite complicated topic for the beginners. You just need to learn the C a bit more. Use your favorite book.

```
void foo(int *ptr1, int *ptr2, int **ptr3)
{
    ptr1 = ptr2;   // ptr1 == ptr2 only in the scope of foo
    *ptr3 = ptr2;  // changes the ptr3
}

int main()
{
    int i = 1, j = 2, k = 3;
    int *x = &i, *y = &j, *z = &k;

    foo(x, y, &z);

    printf("After the call:\n *x = %d, *y = %d, *z = %d\n\n", *x, *y, *z);
}
```

https://ideone.com/GN8IMg

Comment: Thanks a lot for this answer, but it doesn't completely respond to my question. Indeed, if I take your example that means that in my case, "ptr1" doesn't change of value even if in local scope of foo. Do you have an answer for this, please ?

Comment: It does. But it copies only the address not the refrenced object itself

Comment: If so, why my "->" can't acceed to these values

Answer (score 1):

Pointer to pointer copy is available in c. But for constant pointers copying is not permitted.Line

`newPosition = oldPosition;`   will work only if newPosition is not a constant pointer.

The moment you do `newposition = oldPosition;`, newPosition and oldPosition will point to the same location of memory.

Please show  your code , this will help in understanding the issue better.

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to Peter_01 and other people I have solved this matter.
In fact your completely right when you say that the copy of a pointer into a pointer is local.
That's why when I put oldPosition in newPosition it works in fact but just ones.
Because my matter was that I called several times the same waitDeplacement function with between each call a`oldPosition = newPosition` outside the function.
But since the copy of `newPosition = oldPosition` does not really work and that newPosition values is equals to `{0, 0}`. We find at the end that oldPosition take the values  of newPosition which means 0.
Thanks a lot for your help.